# Is it posible to perform the inverse of multidimensional scaling analysis

Tags: clustering, matlab, multidimensional-scaling, fuzzy

We have lot of 3D data and we reduced it to 2D for performing fuzzy clustering and obtaining prototypes. We used some matlab functions that were very well documented. Now we would like to see to which initial 3D points the first prototype found corresponds, so I wonder if we can perform the reverse of MDS, is that possible?

Comment: Exactly how did you "reduce it to 2D"?  Don't you have the original data?

Answer (score 1):

In general, most MDS methods cannot be reversed. If you are using linear MDS method like PCA, DFT, you could use LASSO to reconstruct the original data from the reduced data. Many similar approaches are also referred to as "compressed sensing".

Comment: thanks. I did know nothing about LASSO, can you give me some additional information?

Comment: LASSO (Least Absolute Shrinkage and Selection Operator) is group of methods to solve under-determined linear system with additional constraints. You should be able to find lots info about it on google.